# Pi 3 overall slow performance

Tags: pi-3, performance

I recently bought my first Pi 3 Model B with a 32GB SD Card. I find overall it is very slow. My Atom (Android) is much faster compared to a Pi.

Do I need to do something for the Pi to perform better? I have done updates and upgrades but I did not find any significant improvement. (I am using my Wi-Fi with a  150Mb connection).

Comment: What is the specific task that you claim being slow?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Is it the network performance that you need more information on? Why is the performance of the Pi so crucial to what you are doing? I find my Pi 3 to be fairly adequate performance wise, *given its cost*. I would not be surprised if the atom (processor?) offers more performance.

Comment: What specifically is slow? It's really not fair to compare a relatively old ARM processor to an x86 one; they're in totally different leagues.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider:

- A class 10 SD card.
- Overclock CPU (this can be done from the `sudo raspi-config` menu. You can increase the overclock further by editing the `config.txt` file. There's a good article on how to do this [here](http://www.jackenhack.com/raspberry-pi-3-overclocking/). Be careful, as **overclocking may void your warranty**
- Overclock RAM. [This article](http://www.jackenhack.com/raspberry-pi-3-overclocking/) also shows the process to do it.
- If it's still too slow for you after all that, consider using a more lightweight OS such as Tinycore Linux.